# Having a solution that contains MFC project and console application for unit testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, boost-test

I have a solution which containes serveral projects (An MFC Application and the others are DLL projects). Is it possible to add another console application project (BOOST TEST) to unit test a specific DLL project, without modifying anything in the production MFC application and succeeding in building the whole solution?

I want only the test console application to run as a post build and then launching the prodution MFC application.

Comment: Is it possible? "Yes".

Comment: Can you add another application to your solution? "Yes".
Can you run it after building? "Certainly"
Define a post build event that runs your console application, while your MFC app is set to run as startup project. Just be sure of the correct build order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a series of blog posts on [test-driven development in C++](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/c-unit-tests-with-boost-test-part-1/) that show you step-by-step how to do TDD in C++ with Visual Studio and Boost.Test.  The steps would be nearly identical for your situation with the exception that your console test project depends on the DLL project instead of the static library project that I used in my article.

If I understand you correctly you want the build of the solution to compile and run the tests.  If you say "build and run in the debugger" (F5), you want to compile all the code, run the tests and then run the application if the tests pass.  This is not hard to do.

Set up the console unit test program as outlined in my blog posts and that will make the unit test project compile and run as part of the build.  So if you say "build and run in the debugger" (F5) in Visual Studio, it will build the solution and then run the startup project, e.g. your MFC application.  Since the solution contains the unit test console executable project, it will build that project.  The unit test project has the post-build step to execute the tests, so the tests will run as part of the build.

Because your unit test executable depends on a DLL, you will need to make sure the DLL is found by the executable at run-time.  You may need to add additional commands to your post-build step to copy the DLL to the necessary directory before running the test executable.  You can verify this works properly by setting your unit test project as the startup project and running it in the debugger.

Double check in the configuration manager that all the projects are set to build for your combination of platform and configuration.  Sometimes if you have customized these in your solution when you add a new project it isn't automatically checked to compile in the custom platform/configuration combination.

If this isn't working for you, then add a comment or edit your question to include more specifics about what isn't working.

Comment: Hello LegalizeAdultHood's blog author, I already read (and done) the 5 parts of your good tutorial and I want to thank you about it. The difference is that in my solution I have an MFC project (and it's the startup project) with the other DLL projects and when I launch them with the console application test project, nothing happens IIRC... What I want to do is being able to build the solution and launch the tests as post build and then launch the MFC applciation, I don't know how to manage this. In my big company, they don't use unit tests (only manual testing - debugging with few ASSERTS).